# Chapterhead for * chapter

Tags: formatting

Hello to all connected Stackexchangists.

I have made a modification of my chapterhead and I would like it to be taken into account by \chapter*. How could I manage this ? What I need is the same presentation for chapters Bibliography and indexes.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-blur}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\cpcol{\color[rgb]{.8, .3, 0}}
\definecolor{cpcol}{rgb}{.8, .3, 0}
    \makeatletter
    \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
      \reset@font
      \parindent \z@ 
      \vspace*{10\p@}%
      \hbox{%
        \vbox{\hsize=2cm
          \begin{tabular}{c}
            \scshape \strut{\cpcol\@chapapp{}} \\
            \psblurbox[fillcolor=venetianred!05,linestyle=none]{%
              \vrule depth 10em width 0pt%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              {\LARGE \bfseries \strut {\cpcol\thechapter}}%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              \rput(-0.3,-2.6){\includegraphics[scale=.04,bb=0 0 550 391]{mi.png}}
              \rput(-0.3,-3.2){\tiny \psscalebox{.6 .6}{\color{cpcol}\begin{tabular}{c} La main invisible\\ --- Portrait ---\\Adam Smith\\(1723-1790)\end{tabular}}}
              }
          \end{tabular}%
          }%
        \vbox{%
          \advance\hsize by -2cm
          {\cpcol\hrule}\par
          \vskip 6pt%
          \hspace{1em}%
         {\cpcol \Huge \bfseries #1}
          }%
        }%
      \vskip 100\p@
    }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
aa
\chapter*{Bibliography}
bb
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to do a similar redefinition for `\@makeschapterhead`.

Comment: Sorry Johannes_B, but it seems not to work.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? None of us even knows how the result should look like. `\@makeschapterhead` is the definition for the starred chapters.

Comment: Johannes_B of all evidence there are some mecanism in LaTeX I understand partialy. I want the title Bibliograpy, Index... in my text have the same look than for my chapter. Following our advice, I have tried to add the same text as for \@makechapterhead#1 but wxithout the #1 but this has no effect on the presentation of bibliography

Comment: You copied the code from somewhere and have absolutely no clue what it does, right?

Comment: You are partially right since I have made some modification to the original code. I have trained myself on the job and the consequence is a partial understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine `\@makeschapterhead` for unnumbered chapters.

[image: cyrilleChapterhead]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-blur}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mwe}

\def\cpcol{\color[rgb]{.8, .3, 0}}
\definecolor{cpcol}{rgb}{.8, .3, 0}
    \makeatletter
    \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
      \reset@font
      \parindent \z@ 
      \vspace*{10\p@}%
      \hbox{%
        \vbox{\hsize=2cm
          \begin{tabular}{c}
            \scshape \strut{\cpcol\@chapapp{}} \\
            \psblurbox[fillcolor=red!05,linestyle=none]{%
              \vrule depth 10em width 0pt%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              {\LARGE \bfseries \strut {\cpcol\thechapter}}%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              \rput(-0.3,-2.6){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
              \rput(-0.3,-3.2){\tiny \psscalebox{.6 .6}{\color{cpcol}\begin{tabular}{c} La main invisible\\ --- Portrait ---\\Adam Smith\\(1723-1790)\end{tabular}}}
              }
          \end{tabular}%
          }%
        \vbox{%
          \advance\hsize by -2cm
          {\cpcol\hrule}\par
          \vskip 6pt%
          \hspace{1em}%
         {\cpcol \Huge \bfseries #1}
          }%
        }%
      \vskip 100\p@
    }
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
      \reset@font
      \parindent \z@ 
      \vspace*{10\p@}%
      \hbox{%
        \vbox{\hsize=2cm
          \begin{tabular}{c}
            \strut\\
            \psblurbox[fillcolor=red!05,linestyle=none]{%
              \vrule depth 10em width 0pt%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 1ex%
              \rput(-0.3,-2.6){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
              \rput(-0.3,-3.2){\tiny \psscalebox{.6 .6}{\color{cpcol}\begin{tabular}{c} La main invisible\\ --- Portrait ---\\Adam Smith\\(1723-1790)\end{tabular}}}
              }
          \end{tabular}%
          }%
        \vbox{%
          \advance\hsize by -2cm
          {\cpcol\hrule}\par
          \vskip 6pt%
          \hspace{1em}%
         {\cpcol \Huge \bfseries #1}
          }%
        }%
      \vskip 100\p@
    }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Alpaca}
\blindtext
\chapter*{Wombat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Johannes_B I have forgoten to thank you for your nice answer.